# Sort a list of Objects based on another list sort

Tags: python, list, sorting, object

I've been looking for hours a way to sort objects based on the sorting order of another list of int but I haven't found.

I've tried

```
newList = [element for _,element in sorted(zip(listOfInt, listOfObjects))]
```

but it displays the following error :

```
"'<' not supported between instances of 'Object' and 'Object'"
```

I think the problem is in the "sorted(zip(listOfInt, listOfObjects))" part but I have no idea how to fix this or if there is another way to do it.

Comment: Please post a properly formatted MCVE

Comment: This likely happens because you have duplicates in the ints

Comment: Maybe np.argsort would be useful. You're getting that error because it's trying to sort objects with no key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, your approach would be fine if `listOfInts` did not contain duplicates. Lists and tuples are compared lexicographically, so when there is a duplicate, the second element in each tuple gets compared. To prevent this from happening, you can insert an element into the key before the incomparable objects:

```
newList = [element for _, (_, element) in sorted(zip(listOfInt, enumerate(listOfObjects)))]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write it like so:

```
newList = [
    elem[1]
    for elem in sorted(zip(listOfInt, listOfObjects), key=lambda tup: tup[0])
]
```

The application of `zip` to `List[int]` and `List[Object]` here returns
a sequence of `Tuple[int, Object]`. `sorted`'s `key` allows you to define the sort key relative to elements in the list (in this case, taking the integer). `list`'s `sort` method supports the same argument ([here's the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort)). The outer comprehension fetches the element of the tuple you care about (the `Object`) post-sort. Given what you want is to sort `List[Object]` along the list of integers, this should work.

The reason for this error:

```
'<' not supported between instances of 'Object' and 'Object'
```

is that if you *don't* specify `key`, the comparison here's between `Tuple[int, Object]`s. When each tuple is compared, the `int`s will be compared first, and *then* the `Object`s will be compared if the `int`s can't determine the outcome (so the `Object` must support a comparison method).